# Misalignment between text and icon in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell with a text and icon:

```css
.icon {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<td class="table_cell">
  <span>
    Some text
    <i class="icon"></i>
  </span>
</td>
```

Chrome displays them vertically aligned to each other,
Firefox display the text on the upper left and icon lower right corner.

How can I fix that, thanks!!

Comment: You want `Some text` and icon vertically centered, yes?

Comment: What is definition od table_cell class?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I think Theano is more concerned about the inconsistency of appearance in different browsers.

Comment: @Tim1234 I'd say it's not clear from post content. Maybe author is interested in just solving the issue regardless of reasons for different browser behaviour.

Comment: Yes, i want some text and icon vertically centered. The issue appears only on Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox to provide your table cell content vertical centering. Demo:

```css
.table_cell > span {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* all children will be flex-items including plain text */
  display: flex;
  /* vertically center items */
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  /* move icon to the right */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
]
```

```html
<td class="table_cell">
  <span>
    Some text
    <i class="icon"></i>
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: @TheanoT Glad to hear this! Can you accept my answer (using green check to the left) if it helped you?